# Problem with rotary decoder

Tags: homework, encoder

I am designing a rotary decoder and I am facing an issue:

My comparator output seems to be high always, even if I cover both LDRs or only one or none.

The comparator output goes into the flip-flop which goes to two LEDs. Red will flash if it's rotating clockwise, and yellow if it's rotating anti-clockwise.

I have attached my circuit diagram below.

Any ideas would help.
[image]

Comment: The top comparator will never output a logic 0 because its non-inverting input is at the positive rail. Likewise, the bottom comparator will never output a logic 1 because its non-inverting input is the negative rail (ground in this case).

Comment: Why have you connected the LDRs in series with the LEDs?

Comment: thank you for your responses, i have figured out my error, forgot to create a voltage divider with my ldr oops

Answer (score 3):

This is the canonical way to detect resistance fluctuation with a comparator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fosWsY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Choose R3, R4 to give a reference voltage within the *voltage input common mode range* V<sub>ICR</sub> of the comparator. Somewhere around mid-rail will usually be OK for most comparators, but it may be offset, especially at low supply voltage. Check your comparator datasheet for the specification of V<sub>ICR</sub> (0 V to VCC-2 V for the LM339, other comparators may vary).

Choose R2 to be a resistance value between the largest and smallest extremes of R1, that will make their junction swing well above and below the threshold voltage set up on the reference comparator input.

With your circuit, the reference inputs are at one or the other rail.

The variable inputs hardly move with LDR illumination, as the voltage across a LED barely changes, even as the current through it changes by orders of magnitude.

Sometimes you may make R3/4 into a single potentiometer, for an adjustable reference. The voltage still has to lie within the allowable V<sub>ICR</sub> range.

Do not adjust the reference side to try to pin-point the changing voltage across the LED, as that is very small, and very temperature sensitive. You might get it to work, but it won't stay working for long as soon as the temperature changes. Change the LED for a resistor, delete the resistor in series with the LDR.

Drive the LED from the output of the comparator if you want an indication, with a resistor in series with the LED to limit its current so that it doesn't load the comparator output excessively.

I note that in your schematic, the 5 V battery to the LDRs appears to be floating with respect to the 5 V driving the comparators. This is probably not the case and you have just one supply. If so, show the common ground between them as I have. If there are indeed two, isolated, supplies, you have no assurance of meeting the comparator V<sub>ICR</sub> requirement.